# python string: remove all zeros and one value before each zero in a string

Tags: python, split, naivebayes

I have a naive python question; I need to remove "0 and a value previous to it (any value) from a string "s":

```
s = "8      9243  8607  56     586262       4697424       00000       ik   0       C   S<->L       G   0       G  0       G  0       P    A<->A     R    0"
```

And print the following:

```
8      9243  8607  56     586262       4697424       00000 C   S<->L P    A<->A
```

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "8      9243  8607  56     586262       4697424       00000       ik   0       C   S<->L       G   0       G  0       G  0       P    A<->A     R    0"
new_s = re.sub('\s{6,}', '  ', re.sub('[a-zA-Z\d]+\s+0', '', s))
```

Output:

```
8  9243  8607  56     586262  0000  C   S<->L  P    A<->A
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "hacky" solution.

Note it does not preserve spaces in "s" as in your output (could possibly be preserved if necessary), but the resulting values are the same:

```
# s = ...  # your s string

ss = []

split = s.split()

for i, n in enumerate(split):
    try:
        if split[i+1] == '0':
            pass
        elif n != '0':
            ss.append(n)

    except IndexError:
        pass

print ' '.join(ss)
```

prints:

```
8 9243 8607 56 586262 4697424 00000 C S<->L P A<->A
```